# If I use "all the same" will the sentence be grammatically correct

Tags: american-english, british-english, informal-language

None of his requests were granted, he kept on asking all the same.

If I use "all the same" in this sentence will it be grammatically correct? Thank you.

Comment: There is a different problem with your sentence.  You have put two separate clauses together ("none of his requests were granted" and "he kept on asking all the same") together with only a comma between them.  In English this is an error called a [**comma splice**](https://www.iup.edu/writingcenter/writing-resources/punctuation/comma-splices.html).  If you have two independent clauses, you need to connect them with a conjunction, like "None of his requests were granted **but** he kept on asking all the same."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the usage of "all the same" is grammatically correct in your sentence. The phrase means "regardless of the outcome, he continued to make requests". It serves as an adverbial phrase that modifies the verb "kept on asking."